# Selenium geckodriver unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I tried to **set up the selenium webdriver** with a **geckodriver** on my *raspberry pi 3 in java*. As I tried to launch an **instance of `FirefoxDriver()`** I receive the following error :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: **Unable to find a
>   matching set of capabilities** Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision:
>   '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:42:22.379Z' System info: host: '****',
>   ip: '****', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'arm', os.version:
>   '4.4.38-v7+', java.version: '1.8.0_151' Driver info: driver.version:
>   FirefoxDriver remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:    0: 0x54ba9797 -
>   backtrace::backtrace::trace::hc4bd56a2f176de7e    1: 0x54ba98ff -
>   backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::he3b2a15d39027c46    2: 0x54b03e5f
>   - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::h81babdd86c977032    3: 0x54b04c8f -
>   geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler::create_connection::hf0532ddb9e159684
>   4: 0x54aed4cb - >::run::h2119c674d7b88193    5: 0x54acbcbf -
>   std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h21d98a9ff86d4c25
>   6: 0x54ad31cf - std::panicking::try::do_call::h5cff0c9b18cfdbba    7:
>   0x54c52237 - panic_unwind::__rust_maybe_catch_panic
>                   at /checkout/src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:99    8: 0x54ae59e7 - >::call_box::h413eb1d9d9f1c473    9: 0x54c4c0d3
>   - alloc::boxed::{{impl}}::call_once<(),()>
>                   at /checkout/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:692
>                    - std::sys_common::thread::start_thread
>                   at /checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/thread.rs:21
>                    - std::sys::imp::thread::{{impl}}::new::thread_start
>                   at /checkout/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:84     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>     at
>   java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:138)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
>     at simplePack.Main.main(Main.java:13)

Here is my simple code which causes the error:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Does anyone of you knows the answer concerning this fault?

Thank you very much for your answers!

With best regards,
Philipp

Comment: Is it possible to put the code snippet here?

Comment: @ManojKengudelu I just added it to the question!

Comment: Well, it might just not be the line which you mentioned causing the issue. Could you please refer this? `https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884` . You might need to check the version of Firefox.

Comment: Can you update the question with your code trial including `Main.java:13` and the entire error stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

I have also face the same issue and I have resolved it by setting desired capabilities for gecko driver.

Please follow the code: -

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

It might help you out.